# I want to remove one file after creating it --- node js integration testing

Tags: node.js, testing, logging, integration-testing, mocha.js

I am implementing integration test for logger(winston) using mocha framework.

Suppose I am using `logger.error`. and using this, one file is creating.

I have to check the file is created or not <-- i am able to do it

But I have to delete this file after checking the existance of it.

```
// on file is created and logged the data
logger.error("module.testnamespace.info", "Info message", 1231, 12313); 

// Checking the existance of that file
fs.exists(filePath, function (exists) {
    should(exists).equal(true, 'Log File should exist');
});

// I want to delete that file
fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
```

But here I am getting this error

```
 1) 1. Integration Test Cases for logger wrapper : for `info` method A. Integration Test Cases for logger wrapper : for `info` method a. Check logger file is creating or not:
     Error: ETXTBSY, text file is busy '/web/log/rpc-test.log.2014-12-08'
      at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:760:18)
      at Context.<anonymous> (/web/gin/mochaTest/rpcTest/logger_rpc_test.js:49:10)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/web/gin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:194:15)
      at Runner.runTest (/web/gin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:372:10)
      at /web/gin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:448:12
      at next (/web/gin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:297:14)
      at /web/gin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:307:7
      at next (/web/gin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:245:23)
      at Object._onImmediate (/web/gin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:274:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:336:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.exists(filePath, function (exists) {
    should(exists).equal(true, 'Log File should exist');
    fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
});
```

try this

or if u just wanna delete file then don't check it just delete and let unlink handle it.
try to avoid race conditions

```
fs.unlink('message.txt',function(err,results){
 if(err)   console.log('File Doesnt exists');
  else console.log('deleted!');
});
```

Comment: Actually I am writing the integration test. For that after each and every test I have to delete the file (my requirement). But I am unable to delete it.

Comment: I have already tried your first example. But getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to get `ETXTBUSY` on my own system. I suspect that it is intimately linked with timing issues. However, what you are trying to do requires some finesse with setting up and tearing down your tests. Notably:

1. You should tell Winston to stop using the log file before you delete it. This is the safe way to do it, as it does not assume any specific behavior on the part of your logger, other than that it won't continue using a file once you tell it to stop. See `afterEach` in the sample below.
2. Your test proper should be asynchronous because Winston writes asynchronously. The first time I tried to replicate your issue here, the test failed because *the file did not exist yet*. See `test` in the sample below.

Here is an example:

```
var winston = require("winston");
var should = require("chai").should;
var fs = require("fs");

var filePath = 'file.log';

var logger = new (winston.Logger)();

beforeEach(function () {
    // Because of the afterEach hook, we need add a transport before
    // each test.
    logger.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: filePath });
});

// An example of a test.
function test(done) {
    logger.error(this.test.title);

    // Winston logs to its file asynchronously so using a synchronous
    // check will **NOT** work. This test fails if it does not find a
    // file before the timeout set by Mocha. (2s default).
    function check() {
        fs.exists(filePath, function (exists) {
            if (!exists)
                 // Not present, check again in 0.5s...
                setTimeout(check, 500);
            else
                done();
        });
    }
    check();
}

// Declare two tests to Mocha.
it("test 1", test);
it("test 2", test);

afterEach(function () {
    // Stop using the file before deleting it.
    logger.remove(winston.transports.File, { filename: filePath });
    // If the test failed, we don't have a file to remove so handle it
    // with the try-catch.
    try {
        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
    }
    catch (e) {
        if (code !== 'ENOENT')
            throw e;
    }
});
```